# I seem to lack the shearing punch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Minecraft 1.7, do I now have to kill sheep to collect wool?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25672/in-minecraft-1-7-do-i-now-have-to-kill-sheep-to-collect-wool)

I've not played Minecraft in a while so I'm not sure if this is new in 1.8, but I don't seem to have the shearing touch anymore with sheep. Is there a new way to get wool or do I have to murder all the sheep?

Comment: I think you mean "new in 1.7.3", the latest version as of today. I actually thought 1.8 might be *out*, and had to go check - nope. (I'd have tried an edit, but single-character edits 1.7->1.8 aren't allowed...)

Comment: @Cyclops While it's technically true that 1.8 hasn't been released, Notch and Jeb _have_ confirmed that the buggy, unofficial 1.8 that's been circulating lately was deliberately leaked to whet peoples' appetites/locate additional bugs, and therefore the version number as listed is very possibly the one Rapida is actually playing.

Comment: Dang, I didn't get the memo - I'm out of the *loop* :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 1.7 the [Shears](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shears) got introduced. They will not only let you shear sheep, but also cut off leaves which you will be able to pick up and place again.

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.7 you have to use [shears](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shears) to get more than 1 block of wool from a sheep; without [shears](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shears) you will have to kill the sheep to get only 1 block wool.

[Shears](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shears) are also the only **legit** way of obtaining leaves.